# Datagridview processing startup error in C#, How to solve it?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, datagridview

I am using datagridview in C# .net 4 to develop my application. Some times at the start up of my application, my datagridview are not completely processed and it crashed the application or I have to restart the application.

Suggestions required to get rid of it. I have used "for" loops to create the datagrid's columns and rows inside the datagrids. That might be one of the reason to delayed the processing...

[image: Datagridview not completely process]

```
     private void Create_Datatables()
       {
        ////////////////////  Create data tables, row and Columns in the Datagrids ////////////////////////////////

        DataTable[] Panel_tables = new DataTable[28];

        for (int i = 0; i <= 27; i++)
        {
            Panel_tables[i] = new DataTable();
        }

        int length_col = 16;

        for (int i = 1; i <= length_col; i++)
        {
            Panel_tables[0].Columns.Add(i.ToString());
        }

        int length_row = 2;
        for (int i = 1; i <= length_row; i++)
        {
            Panel_tables[0].Rows.Add("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
        }


        int dg_main = 23;
        for (int i = 0; i < dg_main; i++)
        {
            Panel_tables[i + 1] = Panel_tables[i].Copy();
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = Panel_tables[0];
        dataGridView2.DataSource = Panel_tables[1];
        dataGridView3.DataSource = Panel_tables[2];
        dataGridView4.DataSource = Panel_tables[3];
        dataGridView5.DataSource = Panel_tables[4];
        dataGridView6.DataSource = Panel_tables[5];
        dataGridView7.DataSource = Panel_tables[6];
        dataGridView8.DataSource = Panel_tables[7];
        dataGridView9.DataSource = Panel_tables[8];
        dataGridView10.DataSource = Panel_tables[9];
        dataGridView11.DataSource = Panel_tables[10];
        dataGridView12.DataSource = Panel_tables[11];
        dataGridView13.DataSource = Panel_tables[12];
        dataGridView14.DataSource = Panel_tables[13];
        dataGridView15.DataSource = Panel_tables[14];
        dataGridView16.DataSource = Panel_tables[15];
        dataGridView17.DataSource = Panel_tables[16];
        dataGridView18.DataSource = Panel_tables[17];
        dataGridView19.DataSource = Panel_tables[18];
        dataGridView20.DataSource = Panel_tables[19];
        dataGridView21.DataSource = Panel_tables[20];
        dataGridView22.DataSource = Panel_tables[21];
        dataGridView23.DataSource = Panel_tables[22];
        dataGridView24.DataSource = Panel_tables[23];


        for (int i = 0; i < length_col; i++)
        {
            Panel_tables[24].Columns.Add(i.ToString());
        }

        length_row = 3;

        for (int i = 0; i < length_row; i++)
        {
            Panel_tables[24].Rows.Add("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
        }


        int dg_xio = 27;

        for (int i = 24; i < dg_xio; i++)
        {
            Panel_tables[i + 1] = Panel_tables[i].Copy();
        }

        dataGridView25.DataSource = Panel_tables[24];
        dataGridView26.DataSource = Panel_tables[25];
        dataGridView27.DataSource = Panel_tables[26];
        dataGridView28.DataSource = Panel_tables[27];

    }
```

Comment: post the code.. and use `try catch` block (I think this is happening because of some exception)

Comment: @ Mr_Green, I have posted my code. Kindly have a look on it. Thanks

Comment: use `try catch` and post the exception too (if any).

Comment: definitely, you need try catch blocks it will specify handlers for your exception.

Comment: I added the try catch block and I got this error info
**"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the sieze of the collection. Parameter name : Index"**

Link to the error:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/jBTDe.jpg

Comment: I tried your code and it doesn't throw any axception.

Comment: @ Fuex: Normally i am get exception once in 10 tries. In the normal situation my code works but some time it give exception in in between the line where I assign the datasource to the data tabele.
Like :: 
**dataGridView11.DataSource = Panel_tables[10]; dataGridView12.DataSource = Panel_tables[11];**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try logging in a file with the values of your local variables and see if any of your grid is throwing exception because of variables.

you can use log4net with this configuration

```
<log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
      <param name="File" value="C:\Try\log.txt" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} – %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

  </log4net>
```

Comment: you can use log4net with this configuration

Comment: Hi,

I included the log4net traces to debug my code where I am getting the error but unable to resolve that.

        **dataGridView11.DataSource = Panel_tables[10];
          dataGridView12.DataSource = Panel_tables[11];**

I am getting the error randomly while assigning the datasource to the datatable.